# Error al intentar descargar archivos de servidor ftp con Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, download

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para descargar archivos de mi servidor de Ftp y me sale el siguiente error **(el subproceso se canceló: No se puede evaluar la expresión porque el código está optimizado o un marco nativo está en la parte superior de la pila de llamadas.)** en la linea comentada, el código es **CORRECTO** ya que primero lo probé en un proyecto de prueba y funciono correctamente pero ahora que lo pruebo en mi proyecto me sale el error.
Este es mi código:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://server/" + filename);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");

        FtpWebResponse response =(FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using(MemoryStream stream=new MemoryStream())
        {
            response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=" + filename);
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
            Response.End();//El error sale en esta linea
        }
```

Ya intente poniendo lo siguiente Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); ahora ya no sale el error pero tampoco me descarga el archivo
¿Saben a que se deba el error?
De antemano Gracias!!